# Python TypeError - but why?

Tags: python, typeerror

Can you help me? I don't understand why it does not work.
I see error:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str.

It is strange for me as I found element in list by means of `find_student()` function. So why it does not work in `edit_student()` and in `delete_student()`?

```
database = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'Paw', 'surname': 'Ant'},
            {'id': 2, 'name': 'Nad', 'surname': 'Sus'},
            {'id': 3, 'name': 'Ol', 'surname': 'Ant'}]


def find_student(base): 
    search = input('''For finding student use:
    1 - surname
    2 - id number
    : ''')
    if search == '1':
        surname = input('Enter surname: ').title()
        return [student for student in base if student['surname'] == surname]
    else:
        id = int(input('enter ID: '))
        return [student for student in base if student['id'] == id]


def edit_student(base, find_student):
    student = find_student(base)
    data = input('''Edit:
    1 - name
    2 - surname ''')
    if data == '1':
        student['name'] = input('Enter new name: ')
    elif data == '2':
        student['surname'] = input('Enter new surname: ')
    else:
        print('bad choice')

def delete_student(base, find_student):
    student = find_student(base)
    base.remove(student)
    print('student removed.')

#edit_student(database,find_student)
#delete_student(database, find_student)
```

Comment: `find_student()` returns a list, but you need a dictionary in edit_student when you do `student['name'] = input()`

Comment: `edit_student(database,find_student)`: you don't need to pass `find_student` as an argument: it is already a global function.

Comment: Another potential logical error is that searching for a student based on last name could return multiple records. For example in your database, searching for the `surname` - `Ant` would return 2 students.

Answer (score 0):

```
if data == '1':
    student['name'] = input('Enter new name: ')
elif data == '2':
    student['surname'] = input('Enter new surname: ')
```

The error must occur here.

`student` is an array (you return an array when you call `find_student`) and you use it as is it was a dictionary, with `str` indices.

Answer (score 0):

Check my comments to see how it works.

```py
database = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'Paw', 'surname': 'Ant'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'Nad', 'surname': 'Sus'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'Ol', 'surname': 'Ant'}]


def find_student(base): 
    search = input('''For finding student use:
    1 - surname
    2 - id number
    : ''')
    if search == '1':
        surname = input('Enter surname: ').title()
        print("Returning", [student for student in base if student['surname'] == surname])
        return [student for student in base if student['surname'] == surname]
    else:
        id = int(input('enter ID: '))
        print("Returning", [student for student in base if student['id'] == id])
        return [student for student in base if student['id'] == id]


def edit_student(base):
    matched_students = find_student(base) #some students have the same surname, so this will be a list of students that match the search criteria
    data = input('''Edit:
    1 - name
    2 - surname ''')
    if data == '1':
        for student in matched_students: #iterate though each student that matches
            student['name'] = input('Enter new name: ')
    elif data == '2':
        for student in matched_students:
            student['surname'] = input('Enter new surname: ')
    else:
        print('bad choice')

def delete_student(base, find_student):
    student = find_student(base)
    base.remove(student)
    print('student removed.')

edit_student(database) #you do not need to pass in the find_student function
#delete_student(database, find_student)
```

P.S. I assume you will want to return a value after `edit_student`?

Answer (score -1):

Hi I just solved the problem.
Function find return list, not element in list. That is because I used list comprehension, not for loop.